# How to analyze absolute value functions

Tags: calculus, functions, absolute-value

Can someone provide a systematic way to break ||x| - 1| into its different parts without using a graphical approach? It would be greatly appreciated if the restrictions on each part of the piece wise can be shown.

Comment: You can take different cases, for $x<-1$, $x \in [-1,0]$, $x \in [0,1]$ and $x>1$

Comment: This might help: For all real $x$, the following is true: $$|x|=\sqrt{x^2}$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $$x\geq 0$$ we have $$|x-1|$$ this is $$x-1$$ if $$x\geq 1$$ and $$-(x-1)$$ if $$x<1$$
Can you finish?

Answer (score 0):

A smart student combines analytical methods with a graphical approach ! It is straightforward to show that the function $f(x)$ is zero for $x=+1$ and $x=−1$ and equal to $+1$ for $x=-2$, $x=0$ and $x=2$. This information allows you to draw a picture of the function, which turns out to be $W$-shaped. It is then also straightforward to write down the correct expressions for $f(x)$ on each of the 4 intervals.

Comment: Here, my purpose of asking this question was to see how the algebra is done on a simple case as shown above. My objective by the end of this question is to be able to investigate more complicated examples and more generally, see a pattern to solve question such as ||f(x)| - a| where f(x) is a hard function to visualize and a is a real number. In this case, the answer is very clear when visualizing it but I am looking for the process in which I can show how the graph would look for any complicated function f(x).

Comment: If $f(x)$ is a hard function and you want to take the absolute value, you must find the zeros. You can then change the sign of the function for the negative regions. That is the only "process" I can think of with regards to the absolute value.